# Using firebase analytics on expo sdk 48

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics

I know there has been similar questions, and the solution was to use `expo-firebase-analytics`. However, if you go to the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/firebase-analytics/) You will see the following message:

> Deprecated: This module will no longer be available in SDK 48. Learn how to migrate to React Native Firebase.

When I navigate to the solution which expo [provided](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/firebase-migration-guide.md) it says:

> Migrating from Expo Firebase to React Native Firebase
>
> npm remove expo-firebase-analytics npx expo install
> @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/analytics npx expo
> install expo-build-properties

Then edited my expo.config file as it was suggested even though I am testing it on andoid, not ios:

```
"expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Then using analytics in the simplest possible way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    analytics().logEvent("test_analytics_event", {
      additionaParam: "test",
    });
  }, []);
```

Then I got the following error:

```
 ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
```

I spent more than a week trying to make firebase analytics work. I really need them. I am using expo version 28, testing on my andrid phone, wrtten my app on react native

If anyone can help me setting up analytics that would be really helpful. I am going again and again through the same docs, and I feel I am in a loop, where I got the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to stop using expo go, and use development build instead.

check https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/firebase-migration-guide.md

The Create a development build section.

i was able to solve with a prebuild, however, I'm not able to use expo go anymore, or take advantage of the hot reload.